# Typescript type check in switch statement, feature request or am I doing it wrong?

Tags: typescript

Why doesnt typescript know `f1` returns string when passed argument of "SpecificStringObj" type?

```js
interface F {
  (s: AnyStringObj | SpecificStringObj): string | number;
}

interface AnyStringObj {
  text: string;
}

interface SpecificStringObj {
  text: "specificity";
}

const f1: F = s => {
  switch (s.text) {
    case "specificity":
      return "s";
    default:
      return 1;
  }
};

const stringObj: SpecificStringObj = {
  text: "specificity"
};

const newStringObj: AnyStringObj = { text: f1(stringObj) };
```

This Typescript code fails on the last line **`.text`** in the object, the error message is:

```
[ts]
Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
  Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'. [2322]
t.tsx(6, 3): The expected type comes from property 'text' which is declared here on type 'AnyStringObj'
(property) AnyStringObj.text: string
```

I could solve this with:

```js
const newStringObj: AnyStringObj = { text: f1(stringObj) as string };
```

My question is: Why doesn't typescript know that since im passing a "SpecificStringObj" that the function will return string?

---

Additional question: Is this appropriate for feature request?

Comment: What you are doing is overloading the return method. I'm working on something... It would help me and maybe others if your interface names were CamelCased.

Comment: ok switched to CamelCase

Comment: By the way, the condensed question form should be the title of your question. Helps others with the same problem find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for [function overloading](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads).

```
interface AnyStringObj {
  text: string;
}

interface SpecificStringObj {
  text: "specificity";
}

function f1(s: SpecificStringObj): string;  
function f1(s: AnyStringObj): number;
function f1(s: AnyStringObj | SpecificStringObj): string | number { 
  switch (s.text) {
    case "specificity":
          return "s";
    default:
      return 1;
  }
}


const stringObj: SpecificStringObj = {
  text: "specificity"
};

const newStringObj: AnyStringObj = { text: f1(stringObj) };
```

[Live example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%0D%0Ainterface%20AnyStringObj%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20text%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20SpecificStringObj%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20text%3A%20%22specificity%22%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20f1(s%3A%20SpecificStringObj)%3A%20string%3B%20%20%0D%0Afunction%20f1(s%3A%20AnyStringObj)%3A%20number%3B%0D%0Afunction%20f1(s%3A%20AnyStringObj%20%7C%20SpecificStringObj)%3A%20string%20%7C%20number%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20switch%20(s.text)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20case%20%22specificity%22%3A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%22s%22%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20default%3A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20return%201%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20stringObj%3A%20SpecificStringObj%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20text%3A%20%22specificity%22%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20newStringObj%3A%20AnyStringObj%20%3D%20%7B%20text%3A%20f1(stringObj)%20%7D%3B)

Comment: The casts were not needed, they had remained in there as I tried to work with interfaces but later switched to regular function overloads

Comment: oh ok I see thank you, Titians' answer was more verbose though

Answer (score 1):

Typescript will not do this king of analysis.  When it tries to figure out what `f1` returns it will just look at the signature of the function. In the signature there is no clear relation between `anyStringObj` and `string` (the fact that they are on the same position in the parameter and return unions does not a relationship make).

To help the compiler with this task you can use overloads or conditional types:

Overload version:

```
interface f {
    (s: specificStringObj): string;
    (s: anyStringObj): number;
    (s: anyStringObj | specificStringObj): string | number;
}

interface anyStringObj {
    text: string;
}

interface specificStringObj {
    text: "specificity";
}

const f1: f = ((s:anyStringObj | specificStringObj): string | number => {
    switch (s.text) {
        case "specificity":
            return "s";
        default:
            return 1;
    }
}) as f;

const stringObj: specificStringObj = {
    text: "specificity"
};

const newStringObj: anyStringObj = { text: f1(stringObj) };
```

Conditional type version

```
interface f {
    <T extends anyStringObj | specificStringObj>(s: T):  T extends specificStringObj ? string : number;
}

interface anyStringObj {
    text: string;
}

interface specificStringObj {
    text: "specificity";
}

const f1: f = ((s:anyStringObj | specificStringObj): string | number => {
    switch (s.text) {
        case "specificity":
            return "s";
        default:
            return 1;
    }
}) as f;

const stringObj: specificStringObj = {
    text: "specificity"
};

const newStringObj: anyStringObj = { text: f1(stringObj) };
```